# Django Migration Error With MSSQL Database With Schemas

Tags: python, sql-server, django, pymssql

I just start to create the settings for Django backend (All in Python). I use MS SQL and I run my django in Linux to connect to MSSQL. After setting the databases specifications, I run into the following error.

Given that my database has more than schemas, I assume i have to tell django which schema to use in the database, but i fail to find the right place.

Any ideas ?

My settings:

````
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'MyDB',
        'HOST': '********',
        'PASSWORD': '**************',
        'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
        'USER': 'root',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            },
    },
}```

Error:

```django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Hello there. It looks like you're trying to create an object without specifying a schema name. Please create in a named schema, eg schemaname.tablename\r\n\t (50000) (SQLExecDirectW)"))```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try *'NAME': schema name* in your code instead of 'MyDB'.

I have not used MSSQL however, in case of MYSQL I just mention the schema name. I believe once you specify the 'HOST' and 'PORT' it should connect to the Db. The setting should look like this: (hope it helps)

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'HOST': '***********', # example 'dbserver.your-domain.com'
    'PORT': 'XXXX',
    'NAME': 'schema name',
    'USER': 'root', # always better to use project specific user
    'PASSWORD': '************',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
    },
},
```

}

Comment: So that means I should write MyDB.MySchema? I have tried this before and it will timeout connection to sql as it cannot recognize the database name. But MyDB is a valid name that django can connect to but only fails to write table inside as it does not understand the schéma inside( there are multiples)

Comment: I have tried to use django-db-prefix and put DB_PRE = 'xxx].[' in the settings. This trick I found on webworks fine to add a schema. Now it is able to create the table for django_migrations table. But it failed to create the contenttype table as this trick does not work in the 0001_initial.py in its migration folder. I really have no idea how it can work out....

Comment: Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last): pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '.'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, the solution was to create a new database user with the default schema set to the schema you intend to use. Then use the new database user and login details in your settings.py

```
CREATE LOGIN djangoLogin WITH password='XXXXXXXXXXX';

CREATE USER djangoUser FROM LOGIN djangoLogin WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = yourSchema;

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'djangoUser';
```

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'HOST': '***********', # example 'dbserver.your-domain.com'
    'PORT': 'XXXX',
    'NAME': 'database name',
    'USER': 'djangoLogin',
    'PASSWORD': '************',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
    },
},
}
```